# Ngrok keeps reconnecting with Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ngrok

I'm trying to run my Nextjs App running on localhost:3000 with ngrok. The ngrok tunnel doesn't redirect me nowhere. I only see a short message that ngrok is reconnecting. The app is running on localhost and all seems fine.

Does anybody know what could be the problem? I tried running ngrok with a liveserver on port 5500 and a nuxtjs app on port 3000 and both worked fine.

Comment: Did you try ngrok http 3000?

Comment: Yes :D But I found the solution... I paid for ngrok and now it's working.. as always its all about the benjamins! But thats fine, I like their service anyway.

Comment: Yes. ngrok is awesome